# Low-profile durable electrical connections between microcontrollers and SBC

Tags: raspberry-pi, wiring

I plan to connect an SBC (such as the Jetson, although I'll be using the Pi) to a series of microcontrollers using the GPIO pins over the SPI protocol. What's the best way to connect these devices? I don't really want to just use the generic jumper cables to do this as their contacts can become loose, and they aren't the best to route.

Would it be worth my time to design a PCB shield for the Pi which would break the SPI lane to go to the various MCU's? Is there a better solution?

On top of this (but in the same spirit), I want to run the Pi from an SSD, which I have already been able to do. The read/writes are much better than compared to an SD card, but the typical SATA III to USB 3.0 adapters are so thick and bulky. There are a few that are lower-profile(ish), but I would ultimately like ribbon-style flat right angle connectors, but can't seem to find a product (or combination of) that meets these requirements.

I guess my overall question is what are some of your experiences with low profile wiring? Where may I look / what should I be searching for?

Thanks!

Comment: All of the Jetson devices do have a PCIe lane, for whatever that's worth (https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-modules), and they have the same pinout as the Pi so they should be fine with SPI.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be a 10(or more) pin IDC header and ribbon cable with a connector attached where needed to access each of the sensor boards. I assume the actual number of these boards is low (or you'll run out of select pins).  Something like this.[image]

Your sensor boards may all be restricted to the same select pin, which would require you manipulate wires at each connector, but this would be a reliable connection. These IDC headers are my go-to for wiring to .100 headers. It's more difficult than the single pin jumpers, but 100x more reliable.  If you can choose the select pin on the sensor boards then it gets even simpler.

Is your bandwidth too high for I2C, UART, etc?